# Uncaught ReferenceError: LocalEmpCallback is not defined

Tags: javascript, cshtml

En una vista tengo el siguiente códgio:

```
<tr id="row_@value.EmpleadoID" class="ct-row" data-status="@value.PerfilEmpleadoCentroID">

    <td onclick="LocalEmpCallback(@value.EmpleadoID)">
        <p class="list-text">@value.EmpleadoID</p>
    </td>

    <td onclick="LocalEmpCallback(@value.EmpleadoID)">
        <p class="list-text">@value.IDEmpleadoCentro</p>
    </td>

    <td onclick="LocalEmpCallback(@value.EmpleadoID)">
        <p class="list-text"><span class="label @labelTipo",id="labeltext">@labelText</span></p>
    </td>

    <td onclick="LocalEmpCallback(@value.EmpleadoID)">
        <p class="list-text">@value.InfoContacto.Nombre @value.InfoContacto.Apellidos</p>
    </td>

</tr>
```

También tengo las siguientes funciones de javascript fuera del document.ready:

```
function LocalEmpCallback(IDTipo) {
    console.log("Pasa por aquí");
    $("#modalGListEmpleados").modal('hide');
    GListCallback(2, IDTipo);
};
```

y la otra función:

```
function GListCallback(tipo, IDTipo) {

    var url = '/Permisos/Editar?id=-1&empID=' + IDTipo;
    window.location.href = url;
};
```

No se que estoy haciendo mal pero siempre obtengo el error de:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: LocalEmpCallback is not defined.

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: La función seguramente no esté declarada de manera global, estará encapsulada. Lo correcto en ese caso sería quitar los atributos onclick y añadir esos *event handlers* desde el javascript

Comment: Ok, gracias por la colaboración probaré eso